# Can paypal transfer to bank?

Tags: bank-account, paypal, refund

When you purchase an item through PayPal that is linked to your bank account when PayPal received a refund does the refund automatically transfer from your PayPal account into your linked bank account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can PayPal transfer money automatically from my bank account if I link it in PayPal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75649/can-paypal-transfer-money-automatically-from-my-bank-account-if-i-link-it-in-pay)

Comment: @MarcusD Paypal has changed their policy and practices since 2017. I have a PP account tied to a bank account, and unless I want to get a "Paypal card" I have to manually "accept" PP money into my bank account.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. A refund for a payment paid by Paypal will always go into your Paypal "Balance".

You can however then withdraw those funds back to your back account but it has to be done manually. To do this go to "Add/Withdraw Money" then "Withdraw Money" and put the amount you would like to withdraw from your Paypal balance and then select the linked bank account you want the money to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I had a different experience with it. My purchase with PayPal was canceled and the money was refunded directly to the account via PayPal. I did not have to log into the account manually and transfer the money to the account.